# mysql error 1064 in foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

i have table Movie which is :

```
CREATE TABLE Movie(
    -----
    MID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (MID) );
```

and when i want to create table rent i get the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE Rent(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    MID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (MID) REFRENCES Movie(MID) );
```

error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near 'REFRENCES Movie(MID) )' at line 6
```

please help ty.

Comment: Your `REFRENCES` spelling is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below code and it works fine.

CREATE TABLE Rent( 
`id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
name VARCHAR(20),
MID  int,
FOREIGN KEY `MID` (MID) REFERENCES movie(MID) , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )

Comment: What you are changes in actual query please mention

Comment: Just the references correction and also given the key a name(not necessary).

Comment: You can comment for spelling mistake does not give answer for only spelling correction

Comment: ok, iam a newbie here actually. Thanks for the info.